# Calculate $P(\overline{A} \cup \overline{B})$ What's wrong with my solution?

Tags: probability

- Calculate $P(\overline{A} \cup \overline{B})$ which is a probability.

**Given info:**

$P(A) = \frac{21}{45}$

$P(B) = \frac{1}{3}$

$P(\overline{A \cap B}) = \frac{13}{15}$

**My solution:**

$P(\overline{A} \cup \overline{B}) = P(\overline{B}) + P(\overline{A}) - P(\overline{A \cap B})$

$P(\overline{B}) = \frac{8}{15}$

$P(\overline{A}) = \frac{2}{3}$

So $P(\overline{A} \cup \overline{B}) = \frac{1}{3}$

However, the book didn't find it this way, it used another long method and the result wasn't the same as mine. In the end, the result was $\frac{13}{15}$ which concluded at the end that
$P(\overline{A} \cup \overline{B}) = P(\overline{A \cap B})$

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my method?

Comment: $$P(\overline{A} \cup \overline{B}) = P(\overline{B}) + P(\overline{A}) - \color{red}{P(\overline{A} \cap \overline {B})}$$

and $P(\overline{A} \cap \overline {B}) \ne P(\overline{A \cap B})$.

Comment: @peterwhy But why are they not the same though?

Comment: The easiest way to see might be to draw Venn diagrams, see the ones in [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: @TechnoKnight Also, $\left(\overline A\cap \overline B\right)\subseteq \overline A$, so $P\left(\overline A\cap \overline B\right)\le P\left( \overline A\right)=\frac 8{15}$.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que no aplicas correctamente la ley de Morgan.

$P(A \cap B)^{c}$ y esto es equivalente a P($A^c \cup B^c$).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).